# SQL Injection don't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

I was checking my webpages for SQL Injection, when the main pages didn't responded to it, I created a test script:

```
<?
$a = $_POST["a"];
$username="...";
$password="...";
$database="...";

mysql_connect ('...',$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$ress=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE id='$a'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($ress);

print $row[0];
?>
<form name="form" action="hackMe.php" method="POST">
   <input id="a" name="a" size="150">
   <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But when I try this line:

```
'; UPDATE userinfo SET email = 'steve@unixwiz.net' WHERE email = 'testusr@gmail.com
```

I just get an error, and no change in the database.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Any idea what that error was?

Comment: Are you sur you have "testusr@gmail..." in you database. It seem to missing a ' at the end of the request.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in hackMe.php on line 11

Comment: Because the result of a request is == false when an error occured. You have to check if $ress is false or not

Comment: that means your query is incorrect @sims.

Comment: Yes, I'm having phpMyAdmin open too, to see the change. testusr@gmail IS in there. I don't think I miss a ' in the end, see the script.

Comment: @Sims where are you passing $a's value to your query?

Comment: Script is WORKING fine when I use it "as intended".

Comment: @almasshaikh In the text input.

Comment: did you try executing `SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE id=''` directly in phpmyadmin, because that is what you execute before the update... (maybe add `OR 1 = 1` so you have a result set?)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Yes, working fine, and SELECT username FROM userinfo WHERE id=''; UPDATE userinfo SET email = 'steve@unixwiz.net' WHERE email = 'testusr@gmail.com' is working fine too.

Comment: @Sims ok that might execute in phpmyadmin, but I think you still won't have a result set in `$row = mysql_fetch_array($ress);` so I would add the `OR 1 = 1` so that does not throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote [from the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified

Highlighting by me. `mysql_query()` only allows a single query query per call, the second query behind the `;` is ignored.

To test SQL injection you have to use a query that doesn't need a second one to do harm.

Edit:

It IS possible to allow multiple queries, but you have to explicitly state this in the `mysql_connect()` call.

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, false, 65536);
// defined by MySQL:
// #define CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS 65536 /* Enable/disable multi-stmt support */
```